# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined angular2, very undescriptive error

Tags: angular

This is not a very descriptive error. I have used the array `push` function the same way to generate books in my project and when I do the exact same thing for customers I get the above error. I will post a failing method below and I also have the project on GitHub [HERE](https://github.com/drewjocham/LibraryDemo1.git)

```
ngOnInit(){

        this.bookService.getAllBooks().forEach((books) => {
            this.book = books;
            this.availableFictionBooks = this.bookService.getAvailbleFictionBooks(books);
            this.availableProgrammingBooks = this.bookService.getAvailbleProgrammingBooks(books);
            this.availableNonFictionBooks = this.bookService.getAvailbleNonFictionBooks(books);
        });

        this.customerService.allCustomers().filter(libraryCustomers => {
           this.customers = this.customerService.allCustomers()
        });

        this.bookService.getAllBooks().filter(books => {
           this.allBooks = this.bookService.getAllBooks();
        });

    }
```

The issue is `this.customerService` when I comment out that line everything works fine.

customerService:

```
   generateCustomers():void {

        let id: number = 0;

        this.generateCustomersHelper(id++,"Drew","Jocham",this.bookGenerator());
        this.generateCustomersHelper(id++,"Alex","Williams",this.bookGenerator());
        this.generateCustomersHelper(id++,"Justin","Kavanagh",this.bookGenerator());
        this.generateCustomersHelper(id++,"Mike","Johnson",this.bookGenerator());
        this.generateCustomersHelper(id++,"Kori","Costner",this.bookGenerator());

    }

    getAllCustomers(): Customer[] {

        this.generateCustomers();

        return this.customers;

    }

    generateCustomersHelper(id: number, name: string, lastName: string, booksRented?: Array<IBook>): void {

        let newCustomer = new Customer();

        newCustomer = {id, name, lastName, booksRented };

        this.customers.push(newCustomer);
    }
```

Comment: Comment out all your push functions except the first one that gets hit. If that doesn't show the error uncomment the next one. Keep going until you find out which one is the problem.

Comment: Why BookService.books ? that's the class name , change it to `this.books` and declare your constructor.

Comment: @5313M please see update one

Comment: @5313M I think you are right. I made the methods static. Changing the structure now.

Comment: @5313M I think you were on to something. I did it that way because some of the methods were static. I have changed it all now and I am using this. The issue is in `generateCustomerHelper`.

Comment: I think there is a missed part of the question after `which is calling the following:
`

Comment: @5313M please see the post now. I changed the whole thing. The project is also updated on GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is actually perfectly descriptive. It is saying that, at the time you execute the line `this.customers.push()`, `this.customers` is undefined. This is because you never initialize the variable, and can be fixed by simply adding `= []` to the line where it is declared, the same way you already do in `BookService` for the `books` variable.

Comment: I am so ashamed... Thank you